# How to filter a dictionary based on a value from inner dictionary

Tags: python, dictionary, filtering

do you have an ide how do i filter dict structured like this

```
dictionary = {
    'val1': {"path1": "local"},
    'val2': {"path2": "remote"},
    'val3': {"path3": "remote"},
    'val4': {"test4": "remote"},
}
```

using filter() based value in dictionary inside dictionary?
End result should be that lets say i use filter and i receive

```
filtered_dictionary = {
    'val2': {"path2": "remote"},
    'val3': {"path3": "remote"},
    'val4': {"test4": "remote"},
}
```

Thanks for your time

Comment: what exactly is your filter condition?

Comment: sorry i didn't specify, i have an argument that should match the value of dictionary inside dictionary so if i pass 'remote' the end goal is the second code part i posted

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your condition is, that `"remote"` is somewhere inside the inner `dict` values, you can do it with dictionary comprehension:

```
>>> {k: v for k, v in dictionary.items() if "remote" in v.values()}
{'val2': {'path2': 'remote'}, 'val3': {'path3': 'remote'}, 'val4': {'test4': 'remote'}}
```

that is basically the same as:

```
out = {}
for k, v in dictionary.items():
    if "remote" in v.values():
        out[k] = v

>>> out
{'val2': {'path2': 'remote'}, 'val3': {'path3': 'remote'}, 'val4': {'test4': 'remote'}}
```

Comment: would you mind the logic of that line? I have hard time decoding logic of this list comprehension

Comment: added the expanded version, which is logic-wise the same thing

Comment: Thank you very much

Comment: @MaciekKucharski If you find this answer solves your issue: [What should I ...](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers)